# JS select option based on previous option

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form and I wish that second select option depends on first. It means if I select DEV_1_OLD otption it wont be showed in the second select list. How to do it with JS?

I started something like that but it doesnt work as I expected

```
<select id="s11" name="source" onchange="preapreSelectOptions()">
    <option value="DEV_1_OLD">DEV_1_OLD</option>
    <option value="TEST_OLD">TEST_OLD</option>
    <option value="PROD_OLD">PROD_OLD</option>
</select>

Target Environment:
<select id="s12" name="target" required>

</select>


<script>
     function preapreSelectOptions () {
        var op = document.getElementById("s11").getElementsByTagName("option");
        console.log(op.length);
        var opClone = op;
        for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
            opClone[i] = document.createElement('option');
            // opClone[i].textContent = op[i].value;
            // opClone[i].value = op[i].value;
            document.getElementById('s12').appendChild(opClone[i]);

        }

    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a condition to check if the option you appending is the selected one

```
<select id="s11" name="source" onchange="preapreSelectOptions()">
    <option value="DEV_1_OLD">DEV_1_OLD</option>
    <option value="TEST_OLD">TEST_OLD</option>
    <option value="PROD_OLD">PROD_OLD</option>
</select>

Target Environment:
<select id="s12" name="target" required>

</select>


<script>
     function preapreSelectOptions () {
        var op = document.getElementById("s11").getElementsByTagName("option");
        var selected = document.getElementById("s11")
        for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
            // check if option is not selected
            if(op[i].value != selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value) {
                o = document.createElement('option')
                o.value = op[i].value
                o.text = op[i].text
                document.getElementById('s12').appendChild(o);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement for your code so you can dynamically generate the next option list:

1. Add conditional checking `if value not selected`
2. Make the function `preapreSelectOptions` accept argument so you can automatically generate new list for next `select` element based on current selection.
3. When call the `preapreSelectOptions` function, pass the current element id and next element id.

```js
//Make it accept argument so you can automatically generate new list for next select
function preapreSelectOptions(currentSelectedElement, nextSelectElementId){
  let selectedValue = document.getElementById(currentSelectedElement).value
  
  //list the remain value in case you need it for other logic
  let remainValue = function(){
    let selectOptionList = document.getElementById(currentSelectedElement).children
    let arr = []
    for(var i = 0; i < selectOptionList.length; i++){
        if(selectOptionList[i]["value"] !== selectedValue){
            arr.push(selectOptionList[i]["value"])
        }
    }
    return arr
  }()

  //generate option
  for(var i = 0; i < remainValue.length; i++){
    let newOption = document.createElement("option")
    newOption.value = remainValue[i]
    newOption.textContent = remainValue[i]
    document.getElementById(nextSelectElementId).appendChild(newOption)
  }
}
```

```html
s11<br>
<select id="s11" name="source" onchange="preapreSelectOptions('s11','s12')" value="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DEV_1_OLD">DEV_1_OLD</option>
    <option value="TEST_OLD">TEST_OLD</option>
    <option value="PROD_OLD">PROD_OLD</option>
    <option value="PROD_NEW">PROD_NEW</option>
    <option value="PROD_LATEST">PROD_LATEST</option>
</select>
<br>
s12<br>
<select id="s12" name="source" onchange="preapreSelectOptions('s12','s13')">
</select>
<br>
s13<br>
<select id="s13" name="source">
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but why s12 doubles always results of the list? I wish to have the same list in s11 and then in s12 disable option which is selected in s11

Comment: @AnnaK you can't "disable" option from select list (at least not in conventional way), you can only remove it from select option.